# Insert items matching data attribute to ID's with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a group of spans in a div that I'm try to match and move to a corresponding id.
Each span has a data attribute that matches the parent ID of the target. I'm trying to use jQuery to match the data attributes in the spans and then append them before a separate span in the parent div ID's.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="id-expand-2">
  <a class="thing" href="#">
    <div class="item-title">
      <span>Title 1</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="id-expand-4">
  <a class="thing" href="#">
    <div class="item-title">
      <span>Title 2</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="id-expand-6">
  <a class="thing" href="#">
    <div class="item-title">
      <span>Title 3</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="vid-imgs">
  <span class="item" data-item="id-expand-2"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></span>
  <span class="item" data-item="id-expand-4"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></span>
  <span class="item" data-item="id-expand-6"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></span>
</div>
```

Basically, each span that is in the `vid-imgs` class with the `data-item` would match to the ID of the parent divs and then do an `.append()` right after the `item-title` class.

So the intended output would be something like this:

```
<div id="id-expand-2">
  <a class="thing" href="#">
    <div class="item-title">
<span class="item" data-item="id-expand-2"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></span>
      <span>Title 1</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="id-expand-4">
  <a class="thing" href="#">
    <div class="item-title">
<span class="item" data-item="id-expand-4"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></span>
      <span>Title 2</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="id-expand-6">
  <a class="thing" href="#">
    <div class="item-title">
 <span class="item" data-item="id-expand-6"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></span>
      <span>Title 3</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to match each of those overall.

I was thinking of using each like this:

```
$(".vid-imgs").each(function () {
  var items = $(".item").attr("data-item");
  console.log(items);
});
```

But that only seems to grab the first item in the `vid-imgs` div. I feel like I've done this before, but I've been starting at this thing all day, and I think I need to give my eyes a break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

- `$(".item").attr("data-item");` is getting the value of the `data-item` attribute of the `.item`. If you want to select the item with a specific `id`, you can use the [CSS id selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors)
- You should be looping through the `span`s inside `.vid-imgs`, not `.vid-imgs` itself

```js
$(".vid-imgs span").each(function () {
  var items = $("div#"+$(this).data('item'))
  items.append(this.cloneNode(true))
  this.remove() //remove the span
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id-expand-2">
  <a class="thing" href="#">
    <div class="item-title">
      <span>Title 1</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="id-expand-4">
  <a class="thing" href="#">
    <div class="item-title">
      <span>Title 2</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="id-expand-6">
  <a class="thing" href="#">
    <div class="item-title">
      <span>Title 3</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="vid-imgs">
  <span class="item" data-item="id-expand-2"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></span>
  <span class="item" data-item="id-expand-4"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></span>
  <span class="item" data-item="id-expand-6"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" /></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahhh gotcha. Now I just ned to figure how to append them to the matching ID's of the other divs.

Comment: @ultraloveninja I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: ah HA!!! I was literally going down the `.clone` path! Thanks for confirming my hypothesis!